# How to disable to div tag which works for both InternetExplorer and Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript

How to disable to div tag which works for both InternetExplorer and Mozilla Firefox

I am using document.getElementById("xx").disabled = true; but this is not working in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "disabling a div element"? Only form elements can be disabled, so that the user cannot interact with them. Do you want to prevent events being triggered on the element?

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Please show some more code

Comment: inside the div i have a button . i need to disable it based on a condition

Comment: So why don't you just disable the button then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide and show a div using the style of the div:

```
document.getElementById("xx").style.display = 'none'
document.getElementById("xx").style.display = 'block'
```

Following is a demo:

```
<html>
<body>

<a href="javascript://" onclick="document.getElementById('hideme').style.display = 'none'">hide</a>
<a href="javascript://" onclick="document.getElementById('hideme').style.display = 'block'">show</a>

<div id="hideme">
hello world
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JAgzU/)

Using this function will disable anything within the div, textboxes, etc... I'm assuming that's what you needed.

```
toggleDisabled(document.getElementById('test'));

function toggleDisabled(el) {
    try {
        el.disabled = el.disabled ? false : true;
    }
    catch (e){ }

    if (el.childNodes && el.childNodes.length > 0) {
        for (var x = 0; x < el.childNodes.length; x++) {
            toggleDisabled(el.childNodes[x]);
        }
    }
}​
```

Comment: Just use `"disabled" in el` to check whether it can be disabled

Comment: Not it is, I don't know what version of mozilla you are using unfortunately